# Moving files and dir, even if they already exist in dest

Tags: python, move, shutil

So I want to copy some files and directories from one location to another. Easy enough with `shutil.move`, but I run into problems when the files or directories are already in the destination. The error I get is `Destination path '...' already exists`.

I tried `os.rename` and it didn't produce the desired results either. 
Is there an easy way to copy files and dir structure to another location, even if those files and dir structure are already present in dest?

Here's what I have now:

```
fileList = os.listdir('/Users/john.leschinski/Desktop/testSrc')  
dest = '/Users/john.leschinski/Desktop/testMove'  
for i in fileList:  
    src = '/Users/john.leschinski/Desktop/testSrc/' + i  
    shutil.move(src,dest)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
def move_over(src_dir, dest_dir):
    fileList = os.listdir(src_dir)
    for i in fileList:
        src = os.path.join(src_dir, i)
        dest = os.path.join(dest_dir, i)
        if os.path.exists(dest):
            if os.path.isdir(dest):
                move_over(src, dest)
                continue
            else:
                os.remove(dest)
        shutil.move(src, dest_dir)

src_dir = '/Users/john.leschinski/Desktop/testSrc'
dest_dir = '/Users/john.leschinski/Desktop/testMove'
move_over(src_dir, dest_dir)
```

Comment: I get os.remove(dest) OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

Comment: Maybe you don't have permissions to delete? Or maybe that file is open by another process. Which OS do you use by the way? OS X?

Comment: On OSX 10.6.7, dont think the folder is open or in use.   Also, this looks like it will delete the entier directory of files no? If I have other files that aren't being copied over but need to remain in the dest then this would delete them correct?

Comment: No, it won't delete the entire directory, since `dest` (not `dest_dir`) points directly to the file.

Comment: BTW, if `dest` is a directory, then you would rightly get an error. Maybe you miscopied the code? More maybe the directory that you want to copy contains some subdirectories that also exist in `dest_dir`?

Comment: Then you should have mentioned that. Obviously overwriting a subdirectory is an entirely different matter. See edit.